# Add custom css class to WooCommerce checkout fields

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, woothemes

I would like to be able to add a custom CSS class to my WooCommerce checkout fields. I'm using twitter Bootstrap and I would like to be able to use their .form-control class.

I looked in the woocommerce templates folder in `form-billing.php` but I'm not sure where to add the `.form-control` class to each text field.

Here is the code for `form-billing.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Checkout billing information form
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.1.2
 */

 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
 ?>
 <div class="woocommerce-billing-fields">
<?php if ( WC()->cart->ship_to_billing_address_only() && WC()->cart->needs_shipping() ) : ?>

    <h3><?php _e( 'Billing &amp; Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

<?php else : ?>

    <h3><?php _e( 'Billing Details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', $checkout ); ?>

<?php foreach ( $checkout->checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ) : ?>

    <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php do_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', $checkout ); ?>

<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $checkout->enable_signup ) : ?>

    <?php if ( $checkout->enable_guest_checkout ) : ?>

        <p class="form-row form-row-wide create-account">
            <input class="input-checkbox" id="createaccount" <?php checked( ( true === $checkout->get_value( 'createaccount' ) || ( true === apply_filters( 'woocommerce_create_account_default_checked', false ) ) ), true) ?> type="checkbox" name="createaccount" value="1" /> <label for="createaccount" class="checkbox"><?php _e( 'Create an account?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        </p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_registration_form', $checkout ); ?>

    <?php if ( ! empty( $checkout->checkout_fields['account'] ) ) : ?>

        <div class="create-account">

            <p><?php _e( 'Create an account by entering the information below. If you are a returning customer please login at the top of the page.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

            <?php foreach ( $checkout->checkout_fields['account'] as $key => $field ) : ?>

                <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_registration_form', $checkout ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Do I need to to look in another template file?

Thanks

Answer (score 46):

icc97's answer is almost there but doesn't work.

I took icc97's answer, and debugged it:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'addBootstrapToCheckoutFields' );
public function addBootstrapToCheckoutFields($fields) {
    foreach ($fields as &$fieldset) {
        foreach ($fieldset as &$field) {
            // if you want to add the form-group class around the label and the input
            $field['class'][] = 'form-group'; 

            // add form-control to the actual input
            $field['input_class'][] = 'form-control';
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: What if we want to add classes to certain input types only (ie. textareas)?

Comment: Please remove `public` from this function. It's not a method

Comment: It's working for me. Upvote from mys side.

Answer (score 23):

As @Peanuts pointed out, what if we want to add CSS classes to certain input types only?

After experimenting with the solutions posted here so far, (thanks to everybody!), I've came up with a mod using a simple "switch case", in which the logic is taken from `/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php`. The function allow us to target all the input types at once, be it the default input types or even custom ones.

There's no need to rewrite the `woocommerce_form_field` function to simply change the `$defaults` args for the input types. It is valid to mention that the function also allow us to add much more than just css classes to the fields.

-- So here's the function --

```
/*********************************************************************************************/
/** WooCommerce - Modify each individual input type $args defaults /**
/*********************************************************************************************/

add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_args','wc_form_field_args',10,3);

function wc_form_field_args( $args, $key, $value = null ) {

/*********************************************************************************************/
/** This is not meant to be here, but it serves as a reference
/** of what is possible to be changed. /**

$defaults = array(
    'type'              => 'text',
    'label'             => '',
    'description'       => '',
    'placeholder'       => '',
    'maxlength'         => false,
    'required'          => false,
    'id'                => $key,
    'class'             => array(),
    'label_class'       => array(),
    'input_class'       => array(),
    'return'            => false,
    'options'           => array(),
    'custom_attributes' => array(),
    'validate'          => array(),
    'default'           => '',
);
/*********************************************************************************************/

// Start field type switch case

switch ( $args['type'] ) {

    case "select" :  /* Targets all select input type elements, except the country and state select input types */
        $args['class'][] = 'form-group'; // Add a class to the field's html element wrapper - woocommerce input types (fields) are often wrapped within a <p></p> tag  
        $args['input_class'] = array('form-control', 'input-lg'); // Add a class to the form input itself
        //$args['custom_attributes']['data-plugin'] = 'select2';
        $args['label_class'] = array('control-label');
        $args['custom_attributes'] = array( 'data-plugin' => 'select2', 'data-allow-clear' => 'true', 'aria-hidden' => 'true',  ); // Add custom data attributes to the form input itself
    break;

    case 'country' : /* By default WooCommerce will populate a select with the country names - $args defined for this specific input type targets only the country select element */
        $args['class'][] = 'form-group single-country';
        $args['label_class'] = array('control-label');
    break;

    case "state" : /* By default WooCommerce will populate a select with state names - $args defined for this specific input type targets only the country select element */
        $args['class'][] = 'form-group'; // Add class to the field's html element wrapper 
        $args['input_class'] = array('form-control', 'input-lg'); // add class to the form input itself
        //$args['custom_attributes']['data-plugin'] = 'select2';
        $args['label_class'] = array('control-label');
        $args['custom_attributes'] = array( 'data-plugin' => 'select2', 'data-allow-clear' => 'true', 'aria-hidden' => 'true',  );
    break;


    case "password" :
    case "text" :
    case "email" :
    case "tel" :
    case "number" :
        $args['class'][] = 'form-group';
        //$args['input_class'][] = 'form-control input-lg'; // will return an array of classes, the same as bellow
        $args['input_class'] = array('form-control', 'input-lg');
        $args['label_class'] = array('control-label');
    break;

    case 'textarea' :
        $args['input_class'] = array('form-control', 'input-lg');
        $args['label_class'] = array('control-label');
    break;

    case 'checkbox' :  
    break;

    case 'radio' :
    break;

    default :
        $args['class'][] = 'form-group';
        $args['input_class'] = array('form-control', 'input-lg');
        $args['label_class'] = array('control-label');
    break;
    }

    return $args;
}
```

The function above completely solved the issue of targeting the checkout form inputs all at once, which is really straight forward for the checkout form default input types or even custom new ones. It seems not to be possible though, to print each input type html output without creating a new function as @abhisek shows on his answer.

### Bonus

It seems that the function might also affect other forms fields printed by WooCommerce's functions or templates outside the checkout page.
I've managed to conditionally apply the function only when on the checkout page by using the `is_page()` function. Your checkout page might have a different slug, so change that to reflect it accordingly.

If you need to apply the function only for the checkout page, do as follows:

Comment add_filter()

`//add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_args','wc_form_field_args', 10, 3);`

And use add_action instead

`add_action('woocommerce_form_field_args', 'wc_form_field_args', 10, 3);`

```
function wc_form_field_args( $args, $key, $value = null ) {

...

// Right after 
    return $args;

// Place the following

if ( !is_page('checkout') ) {
  add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_args','wc_form_field_args', 10, 3);
} else {
  remove_filter('woocommerce_form_field_args','wc_form_field_args', 10, 3);
}


}
```

After that, the function will only affect the checkout page form.

Comment: @Monecchi it works, but it doesn't affect only the checkout form. Is there a way to apply this only for the checkout form and at the same time to target only some field types (input, textarea,...)?

Comment: @Sefran2  I couldn't replicate this. What else does the function affect? In order to target only the fields you want, simply remove the cases you don't want from the `switch()` function.

Comment: @Sefran2 - After inspecting it further, indeed it seems that other woocommerce's forms are affected by the function. I've just checked for the checkout page with the `is_page()` function in order to remove the filter in case it is not the checkout page. I've update the function.

Comment: @AdrianoMonecchi: If the add_filter is commented, what is added and removed in the action? However, you gave me an hint and in the filter I've added the if (is_checkout()) and now all it works. Thanks :)

Comment: @Sefran2 Please check the "Bonus" part of the answer for explanation. The `add_action()` just triggers the function, which in turn does a conditional check if you're on the checkout page and then adds or removes the filter accordingly. I've tested it on my end and it works. You then have to modify the function again to target only the field types you want. It shouldn't mess up with other forms fields printed by woocommerce functions or templates outside the checkout page.

Answer (score 4):

@Chetan's [link and run](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers?rq=1) answer does kind of give you what you want, but as ever they're never very good answers.

The best resource for this is the WooCommerce Codex page on [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/).

In the 'Customizing WooCommerce Checkout Field Labels and Placeholder Text' in Chetan's page you have the following code which you need to add to your functions.php, I've modified it in such a way that it should do what you want, but I haven't tested the code:

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'my_theme_custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function my_theme_custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     foreach ($fields as $fieldset) {
         foreach ($fieldset as $field) {
             $field['class'] = array('form-control');
         }
     }
     return $fields;
}
```

Comment: The above does not work for me. Instead I've hooked in `woocommerce_form_field_args` filter in order to pass the class name as follows: `add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_args','wc_form_field_args',10,3);
function wc_form_field_args($args, $key, $value) {
$args['input_class'][] = 'form-control';
return $args;
}`

Comment: @AdrianoMonecchi see Dan Smart's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25311583/327074) - he debugged my answer

Answer (score 3):

I am fixed the issue by defining a custom function. The logic is taken directly from wc-template-functions.php (I am not sure if this is the right way but it does solve the problem).

```
/*
 * Custom form field function for Bootstrap 3
 */
function bootstrap_woocommerce_form_field( $key, $args, $value = null ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'type'              => 'text',
        'label'             => '',
        'placeholder'       => '',
        'maxlength'         => false,
        'required'          => false,
        'class'             => array(),
        'label_class'       => array(),
        'input_class'       => array(),
        'return'            => false,
        'options'           => array(),
        'custom_attributes' => array(),
        'validate'          => array(),
        'default'           => '',
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults  );

    if ( ( ! empty( $args['clear'] ) ) ) $after = '<div class="clear"></div>'; else $after = '';

    if ( $args['required'] ) {
        $args['class'][] = 'validate-required';
        $required = ' <abbr class="required" title="' . esc_attr__( 'required', 'woocommerce'  ) . '">*</abbr>';
    } else {
        $required = '';
    }

    $args['maxlength'] = ( $args['maxlength'] ) ? 'maxlength="' . absint( $args['maxlength'] ) . '"' : '';

    if ( is_string( $args['label_class'] ) )
        $args['label_class'] = array( $args['label_class'] );

    if ( is_null( $value ) )
        $value = $args['default'];

    // Custom attribute handling
    $custom_attributes = array();

    if ( ! empty( $args['custom_attributes'] ) && is_array( $args['custom_attributes'] ) )
        foreach ( $args['custom_attributes'] as $attribute => $attribute_value )
            $custom_attributes[] = esc_attr( $attribute ) . '="' . esc_attr( $attribute_value ) . '"';

    if ( ! empty( $args['validate'] ) )
        foreach( $args['validate'] as $validate )
            $args['class'][] = 'validate-' . $validate;

    switch ( $args['type'] ) {
    case "country" :

        $countries = $key == 'shipping_country' ? WC()->countries->get_shipping_countries() : WC()->countries->get_allowed_countries();

        if ( sizeof( $countries ) == 1 ) {

            $field = '<div class="form-group form-row ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '_field">';

            if ( $args['label'] )
                $field .= '<label class="' . implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) .'">' . $args['label']  . '</label>';

            $field .= '<strong>' . current( array_values( $countries ) ) . '</strong>';

            $field .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="' . current( array_keys($countries ) ) . '" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . ' class="country_to_state" />';

            $field .= '</div>' . $after;

        } else {

            $field = '<div class="form-group form-row ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '_field">'
                    . '<label for="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="' . implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) .'">' . $args['label'] . $required  . '</label>'
                    . '<select name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="country_to_state form-control country_select" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . '>'
                    . '<option value="">'.__( 'Select a country&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) .'</option>';

            foreach ( $countries as $ckey => $cvalue )
                $field .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $ckey ) . '" '.selected( $value, $ckey, false ) .'>'.__( $cvalue, 'woocommerce' ) .'</option>';

            $field .= '</select>';

            $field .= '<noscript><input type="submit" name="woocommerce_checkout_update_totals" value="' . __( 'Update country', 'woocommerce' ) . '" /></noscript>';

            $field .= '</div>' . $after;

        }

        break;
    case "state" :

        /* Get Country */
        $country_key = $key == 'billing_state'? 'billing_country' : 'shipping_country';

        if ( isset( $_POST[ $country_key ] ) ) {
            $current_cc = wc_clean( $_POST[ $country_key ] );
        } elseif ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $current_cc = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id() , $country_key, true );
            if ( ! $current_cc) {
                $current_cc = apply_filters('default_checkout_country', (WC()->customer->get_country()) ? WC()->customer->get_country() : WC()->countries->get_base_country());
            }
        } elseif ( $country_key == 'billing_country' ) {
            $current_cc = apply_filters('default_checkout_country', (WC()->customer->get_country()) ? WC()->customer->get_country() : WC()->countries->get_base_country());
        } else {
            $current_cc = apply_filters('default_checkout_country', (WC()->customer->get_shipping_country()) ? WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() : WC()->countries->get_base_country());
        }

        $states = WC()->countries->get_states( $current_cc );

        if ( is_array( $states ) && empty( $states ) ) {

            $field  = '<div class="form-group form-row ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '_field" style="display: none">';

            if ( $args['label'] )
                $field .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="' . implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) .'">' . $args['label'] . $required . '</label>';
            $field .= '<input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key )  . '" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . ' placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args['placeholder'] ) . '" />';
            $field .= '</div>' . $after;

        } elseif ( is_array( $states ) ) {

            $field  = '<div class="form-group form-row ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '_field">';

            if ( $args['label'] )
                $field .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="' . implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) .'">' . $args['label']. $required . '</label>';
            $field .= '<select name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="state_select form-control " ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . ' placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args['placeholder'] ) . '">
                <option value="">'.__( 'Select a state&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) .'</option>';

            foreach ( $states as $ckey => $cvalue )
                $field .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $ckey ) . '" '.selected( $value, $ckey, false ) .'>'.__( $cvalue, 'woocommerce' ) .'</option>';

            $field .= '</select>';
            $field .= '</div>' . $after;

        } else {

            $field  = '<div class="form-group form-row ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '_field">';

            if ( $args['label'] )
                $field .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="' . implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) .'">' . $args['label']. $required . '</label>';
            $field .= '<input type="text" class="form-control input-text ' . implode( ' ', $args['input_class'] ) .'" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"  placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args['placeholder'] ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . ' />';
            $field .= '</div>' . $after;

        }

        break;
    case "textarea" :

        $field = '<div class="form-group form-row ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '_field">';

        if ( $args['label'] )
            $field .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="' . implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) .'">' . $args['label']. $required  . '</label>';

        $field .= '<textarea name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="form-control input-text ' . implode( ' ', $args['input_class'] ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args['placeholder'] ) . '"' . ( empty( $args['custom_attributes']['rows'] ) ? ' rows="2"' : '' ) . ( empty( $args['custom_attributes']['cols'] ) ? ' cols="5"' : '' ) . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . '>'. esc_textarea( $value  ) .'</textarea>
            </div>' . $after;

        break;
    case "checkbox" :

        $field = '<div class="checkbox form-row ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '_field">
                <label for="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="checkbox ' . implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) .'" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . '>
                    <input type="' . esc_attr( $args['type'] ) . '" class="input-checkbox" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="1" '.checked( $value, 1, false ) .' />'
                    . $args['label'] . $required . '</label>
            </div>' . $after;

        break;
    case "password" :

        $field = '<div class="form-group form-row ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '_field">';

        if ( $args['label'] )
            $field .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="' . implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) .'">' . $args['label']. $required . '</label>';

        $field .= '<input type="password" class="form-control input-text ' . implode( ' ', $args['input_class'] ) .'" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args['placeholder'] ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . ' />
            </div>' . $after;

        break;
    case "text" :

        $field = '<div class="form-group form-row ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '_field">';

        if ( $args['label'] )
            $field .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="' . implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) .'">' . $args['label'] . $required . '</label>';

        $field .= '<input type="text" class="form-control input-text ' . implode( ' ', $args['input_class'] ) .'" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args['placeholder'] ) . '" '.$args['maxlength'].' value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . ' />
            </div>' . $after;

        break;
    case "select" :

        $options = '';

        if ( ! empty( $args['options'] ) )
            foreach ( $args['options'] as $option_key => $option_text )
                $options .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '" '. selected( $value, $option_key, false ) . '>' . esc_attr( $option_text ) .'</option>';

            $field = '<div class="form-group form-row ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['class'] ) ) .'" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '_field">';

            if ( $args['label'] )
                $field .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="' . implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) .'">' . $args['label']. $required . '</label>';

            $field .= '<select name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="select form-control" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . '>
                    ' . $options . '
                </select>
            </div>' . $after;

        break;
    default :

        $field = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_form_field_' . $args['type'], '', $key, $args, $value );

        break;
    }

    if ( $args['return'] ) return $field; else echo $field;
}
```

Don't forget to replace all occurrences of `woocommerce_form_field` with `bootstrap_woocommerce_form_field` Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* New Checkout fields */
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_args', 'custom_wc_form_field_args', 20, 3);
function custom_wc_form_field_args($args, $key, $value)
{
    if (is_checkout()) {

    if ($key != 'billing_phone' && $key != 'billing_email' && $key != 'billing_postcode' && $key != 'billing_country') {
        $args['class'] = array('inline-input');

    }elseif($key == 'billing_country'){
        $args['class'] = array('inline-input update_totals_on_change');
    }
    else {
        $args['class'] = array();
    }
    // if ($key == 'billing_country' || $key == 'shipping_country') {
    //     $args['class'] = array('inline-input', 'hidden');
    // }
    // $args['input_class'] = array('inline-text');
    if ($args['type'] == 'checkbox') {
        $args['label_class'] = array('custom-checkbox');
    } else {
        $args['label_class'] = array('sr-only');
    }
}
return $args;
```

}