# Add Bootstrap form control class to woocommerce address fields

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

I'm trying to add the bootstrap class "form-control" to all the woocommerce address fields under my account and also when you do a check out.

Basically I want to add the class "form-control" to all the billing address and shipping address input fields. I've tried everything and also looked at the documentation here https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

I also found another post [Add custom css class to WooCommerce checkout fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943791/add-custom-css-class-to-woocommerce-checkout-fields)

I've tried everything but nothing seems to update the fields or add a class. I've tried just adding one of the examples in my functions.php file but it doesn't seem to work.

Would anyone be able to help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_args',  'wc_form_field_args',10,3);
  function wc_form_field_args($args, $key, $value) {
  $args['input_class'] = array( 'form-control' );
  return $args;
}
```

Comment: Appears to work well - form-control class added to checkout field Input tag.