# How to add icons to checkout tags using Hooks?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

How can I add an icon next to the WooCommerce Checkout page `Input` tag, which when tapped shows a `Tooltip` with text?

How to edit checkout `inputs` with `hooks` in WooCommerce?

I want to add an icon inside the billing details, in the phone field input, which is `billing_phone`, in the WooCommerce checkout, so that when we touch it or hover over it, the `Tooltip` will display a text.

I can't find the way to modify each `input`, I have seen that I can add elements before the Billing section with the Hook `woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form` and after the Billing section with the following Hook `woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form`

**I EDIT THE QUESTION**

With the help of @Mtxz , I managed to do tests and thanks to one of its functions, I managed to add the icon at checkout.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'add_code_to_checkout_phone_field', 10, 4 );

function add_code_to_checkout_phone_field( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    if ( $key === 'billing_phone' ) {
        $content = '<strong>
        <div class="colocandolo">
        <div class="tooltip top">
         <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ryJxTmp6/marron-Interro.png" width="20px"/>
          <span class="tiptext">
           Esto es un texto
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </strong>';
$field = preg_replace('/<\/p>/', $content . '</p>', $field);
    }

    return $field;
}
```

the problem is that the icon is displayed at the top of the `"Billing Details"` form, below the title.
You can see it in the following image:

[image]

What do I need to change in the @Mtxz function so that the icon is displayed next to the "Phone" `label`?

I have tried this example to guide me in the creation of the `function` to achieve what I am looking for, but it does not work
Can I add icons to the Checkout form `labels` from the `Hooks`?

Why doesn't the function I created work?
I've searched but I can't find the right hook to add the icon that shows a Tooltip next to the input labels.
If this can't be done using `Hooks`, and there isn't a plugin that does it, maybe it can be done by editing a WooCommerce template, I imagine so.

What is the template that should be customized?

You can see what I'm looking for in any WooCommerce admin page, for example in wp-admin => settings => General .
All the fields have an icon that is a question mark and shows information in a Tooltip when we touch the icon.

I have also added a screenshot
https://ibb.co/5Y2k2PL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtPoq.png)

I have created a small demo with html and css, but I don't know how I can get this implemented in WooCommerce

```css
.colocandolo{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(175, 76, 6); */
}
.tooltip .tiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: rgb(93, 69, 4);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgb(93, 69, 4);
}
.tooltip .tiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.tooltip:hover .tiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip.top .tiptext{
  margin-left: -60px;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
}

.tooltip.top .tiptext::after{
  margin-left: -5px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border-color: rgb(93, 69, 4) transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="colocandolo"> 
    <div class="tooltip top">
     <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ryJxTmp6/marron-Interro.png" width="20px"/>
      <span class="tiptext">
  This is the text that we should display
        </span>
      </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: _"I want to do this without using a Plugin"_ - you're still going to have to write some code. You need to go and familiarize yourself with WP's hook/filter functionality. https://woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#adding-a-custom-special-field

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I'll try to do something. I came here because I thought you suggested ideas because of the lot of talent that goes through this place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did not find a solution with `php` functions, you can do it with `css`, only instead of an icon, we add the question mark: `"?"`, next to the `"Phone" Label`.

```
p.form-row:has(>label[for="billing_phone"]) {
  position:relative;
 
 }
 
 p.form-row:has(>label[for="billing_phone"]):after{
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  top: 1px;
  left: 79px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #927124;
  content: "?";
  color: #F1EAD6;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 900;
 }
 
 
 p.form-row:has(>label[for="billing_phone"]):before{
   display: block;
   content: "This is the text that we should display";
   visibility: collapse;
   width: 120px;
   background-color: rgb(93, 69, 4);
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 3px;
   padding: 10px;
   font-size:0.9em;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9990;
   left: 99px;
   top: -13px;
   box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgb(93, 69, 4);
 }
 
 p.form-row:has(label[for="billing_phone"]):hover:before{
   visibility: visible;
 }
 p.form-row:has(label[for="billing_phone"]:hover, span:hover):before{
   visibility: collapse;
 }
```

Or you can add inside the `input`, with your own example, and the icon, where you like the most.
I have seen it both ways.

I hope it is useful

```
label[for="billing_phone"] + span {
  position:relative;
 }
 
 label[for="billing_phone"] + span > input.input-text {
  padding-right:34px;
 }
 
 label[for="billing_phone"] + span:before{
   width: 24px;
   height: 24px;
   top: -7px;
   right: 8px;
   
   content: "";
    display: block;
   background: url("ttps://i.postimg.cc/ryJxTmp6/marron-Interro.png") no-repeat 0 0;
   background-size: 100%;
   position:absolute;
 }
 
 
 label[for="billing_phone"] + span:after{
   display: block;
   content: " El número de teléfono lo necesitamos por si tuviéramos problemas con el pedido";
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 120px;
   background-color: rgb(93, 69, 4);
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 3px;
   padding: 10px;
   font-size:0.9em;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9990;
   right:2px;
   top:8px;
   box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgb(93, 69, 4);
 }
 
 label[for="billing_phone"] + span:hover:has(>input:not(:hover)):after{
    visibility: visible;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two way to handle this :

1. Using CSS Class and JS

I would add a custom class to the desired input. JS would be used to trigger the tooltip, and retrieve text from a custom HTML attribute.
This solution may not be compatible with your CSS only + custom HTML markup tooltip.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'customize_checkout_fields' );

function customize_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_phone' ][ 'class' ][]           = 'custom-class';
    $fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_phone' ][ 'custom_attributes' ] = [
        'data-text' => 'custom text'
    ];

    return $fields;
}
```

2. Edit Woocommerce HTML Output

Woocommerce billing input cannot be override using a template file. They are generated from the `woocommerce_form_field()` method, which is called for every input in `$checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' )` (`form-billing.php`).

Looking at the `woocommerce_form_field()` code, I can see a `woocommerce_form_field` hook allowing us to edit the final input HTML output.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'add_code_to_checkout_phone_field', 10, 4 );

function add_code_to_checkout_phone_field( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    if ( $key === 'billing_phone' ) {
        $content = '<strong>Additional content</strong>';
        $field = preg_replace('/<\/p>/', $content . '</p>', $field);
    }

    return $field;
}
```

This code will edit the `billing_phone` HTML output, and add content before the `</p>` (so at the end, but IN the input "top-level" container).
You can add your tooltip here, and handle positioning with something like `position: relative` on the parent container, and absolute positioning on the tooltip.

You can dump the "$field" value to check your input HTML, and adapt the regex part.

Note: I first tried to wrap the entire `$field` HTML in a custom `<div>`. But it ended up breaking my form grid (which may be specific to my implementation on my test env). So I used a regex to inject the custom HTML code in the input container.

See:

- https://woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/
- [How should I change the woocommerce_form_field HTML Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992290/how-should-i-change-the-woocommerce-form-field-html-structure)
- [Add custom css class to WooCommerce checkout fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943791/add-custom-css-class-to-woocommerce-checkout-fields)

Comment: Thanks for spend your time on me @Mtxz . I have reviewed your proposals and I am still reviewing the links you have offered me. They have very good information, but it is being a little difficult for me to understand it. I think the best option is to add the icon that shows the Tooltip with 'custom_attributes', what do you think? The code that you show me, I can't place it in my work, I don't know how to modify it exactly. I only get what we need, I don't know how to edit your code Thanks, I'll keep looking by reading the links you've shown me

Comment: The thing is: custom attributes only allow you to add HTML attributes to the input. 
Your custom tooltip has a custom HTML markup: so you need to add the custom tooltip HTML to the input container to display it above it. 
From this, I would choose option 2. Add the option 2 code to your theme function.php file. See if the "Additional content" text is displayed next to billing_phone input on the woo checkout page. If so: you can add your tooltip HTML here. If not: dump the "$content" variable inside the "if" statement to check how to update the regex.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering. I've been doing some tests.
Actually if "Additional content" is displayed, but it is displayed at the top of the Phone input.
should be displayed next to the label says "Phone". [See screenshot](https://ibb.co/tqHr8vD). On the other hand, I have added my html code in the $content variable, but the icon is displayed at the top of the "Billing Details" form. You can see it, edit the question adding the code got from your answer.
I hope you can give me an idea of why the icon is at the top instead of next to the "Phone" label

Comment: As I said, once you have the tooltip content output IN the input container: you can use CSS to position your tooltip. Set `position: relative` to the input container. Then set `position: absolute` on the tooltip <strong>. Then you should be able to position your tooltip wherever you want in the input container. You can also use z-index to make the tooltip "on top" of the input.

Comment: Ah sorry: the tooltip isn't outputed in the input container? Have you tried dumping the  $content variable to be sure the preg_replace matches your HTML content?

Comment: I thank you for the time you have dedicated to me, but I don't quite understand what I should do, I'm confused. I must use the Google translator and it may not interpret your words properly. I don't know exactly what you want to tell me. I will continue looking for information with your proposal. I am very grateful, but I still don't understand, I will keep studying and trying to understand your idea until I get it. I did several tests, but if I don't understand what you want to tell me, I can do millions of tests without it working, or by chance. But I want to understand how it works

Comment: First step: can you var_dump the "$content" variable within the "if ( $key === 'billing_phone' ) " please

Comment: I don't understand what you want to tell me, I need to use the translator to communicate with you and you don't want to tell me with your words. I'm confused

Comment: I have added var_dump($content) , the result is that the icon on top is duplicated and you can also see the following: "sting(348)". As you can see in the [inspector screenshot](https://ibb.co/Hqv6Qw2), you are duplicating the icon. I don't understand what is happening, do you know what is happening @Mtxz

Comment: ok so we see your input is wrapped in a <strong> tag. So edit the preg_replace to this: "preg_replace('/<\/strong>/', $content . '</strong>', $field);" and test please

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried the change, and it doesn't show anything at all. I doubt we can do it with this function anymore. Of course, I am very grateful for your collaboration.

Comment: Well, sorry to hear. I could make it work and the code should help you to do what you want. Good luck

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work, none of the options work

Answer (score 1):

I modified(by appending a CSS class to the label and replacing the label content with an HTML icon and tooltip) your function as below:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'add_code_to_checkout_phone_field', 10, 4 );

function add_code_to_checkout_phone_field( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    if ( $key === 'billing_phone' ) {
        $args['label_class'] .= ' checkout-tooltip'; // add CSS class to label

        $content = '<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ryJxTmp6/marron-Interro.png" width="20px" class="tooltip-icon"/>
            <span class="tooltip-text">Esto es un texto</span>';

        // add the icon and tooltip to the label
        $field = str_replace( '<label', '<label data-tooltip="' . esc_attr__( 'Phone tooltip', 'your-text' ) . '"', $field );
        $field = str_replace( '<label', '<label class="checkout-tooltip-label"', $field );
        $field = str_replace( '</label>', $content . '</label>', $field );
        $field = str_replace( '<input', '<input aria-describedby="billing_phone_tooltip"', $field );
    }

    return $field;
}
```

I have tested the above on a woocommerce store and it works as expected.
[image]
Used CSS to hide it by default and show on hover.

Comment: Thanks for your support @AmanHirani . I've added your function to my site, but it doesn't work. The icon is not shown and the text is shown directly. See [the screenshot](https://ibb.co/P153RXS) for yourself. As you can see, with your function in the inspector, not even the icon is shown. I am using a css, perhaps you use another and that is why the icon is not shown and the text is shown directly in the input. My css is different from yours, maybe this is the problem. How can I correct it? You can see my styles in example that I am using and have added to the question. Thank you

Comment: Ideally, the icon and text both should display above the phone input block. I suspect it might be an issue with the  HTML code used to display the icon(since the text is being displayed). Instead use HTML Unicode character like below:

$content = '<span class="tooltip-icon">&#x2753;</span>
            <span class="tooltip-text">Esto es un texto</span>';

Comment: Here is the updated screenshot (https://ibb.co/gwLkPK6) with basic css to display text on hover.

Comment: Thanks again. I have made all the changes that you have suggested, I have tested this code on a website that is clean, without more functions in the function.php file, I have added the css that you show in the screenshot, but only the question " ?" and the text "this is a text" within the input, without the question having any functionality. I think I'll look for another alternative. I am sorry for the time you have spent to help me, and I am very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

ok, you can do this by adding the following code in your functions.php

```
function add_phone_icon_tooltip( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    if ( $key === 'billing_phone' && is_checkout() ) {
        $icon = '<i class="fas fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'. esc_attr__( 'Custom tooltip text goes here', 'textdomain' ) . '">X</i>';
        $field = str_replace( '</label>', ' ' . $icon . '</label>', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'add_phone_icon_tooltip', 10, 4 );
```

This code is assuming you have FontAwesome icons pack and will display the icon next to your phone number. If you hover it, a custom text will appear [like here](https://prnt.sc/IRiFQFK_3c2v).

You should see a icon or a "X". If you have font awesome, remove the x and you'll have just the icon.

Enjoy.

Comment: check this @gemita

Answer (score 0):

try using this code in your theme's `functions.php` to place the `icon`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'add_code_to_checkout_phone_field', 99, 4 );

function add_code_to_checkout_phone_field( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    if ( $key == 'billing_phone' ) {
        $content = '<span class="tooltip top" style="display:inline-block">
         <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/ryJxTmp6/marron-Interro.png" width="20px"/>
          <span class="tiptext">
           Esto es un texto
            </span>
          </span>';
        $field = preg_replace('/<\/label>/ism',  "$content</label>", $field);
    }

    return $field;
}
```

I didn't fix your CSS if it was helpful I would be happy to help you with CSS too.

Comment: Im sure you're doing something wrong! and also the image is not found. show the image and I help you!

Comment: check the picture again https://ibb.co/y0X3z95

Comment: try something... put an `exit()` or `var_dump()` in this function and see if it runs! I think the function is not running! if the code in your Question is working so this should be too! I'm testing it in a wordpress right now!

Comment: @gemita the picture shows that the code didn't even execute!

Comment: @gemita my result is this! https://ibb.co/3Bm0LFv there should be a span added.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this with pure jQuery and CSS

```
add_action('wp_footer', function() {
    if ( is_checkout() ) { ?>
<style>
    #billing_phone_field .woocommerce-input-wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }
    #billing_phone_field .woocommerce-input-wrapper .tooltip .icon, #billing_phone_field .woocommerce-input-wrapper .tooltip .title {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 0;
    }
    #billing_phone_field .woocommerce-input-wrapper .tooltip .icon {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }
    #billing_phone_field .woocommerce-input-wrapper .tooltip .title {
        top: 20px;
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: none;
    }
    /* #billing_phone_field .woocommerce-input-wrapper .tooltip .icon:hover + .title {
        display: block;
    } */
</style>
<script>
    (function($) {

        const title = 'This is the text that we should display'
        const toolTip = '<div class="tooltip"><svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title>'+title+'</title><path d="M15.07,11.25L14.17,12.17C13.45,12.89 13,13.5 13,15H11V14.5C11,13.39 11.45,12.39 12.17,11.67L13.41,10.41C13.78,10.05 14,9.55 14,9C14,7.89 13.1,7 12,7A2,2 0 0,0 10,9H8A4,4 0 0,1 12,5A4,4 0 0,1 16,9C16,9.88 15.64,10.67 15.07,11.25M13,19H11V17H13M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12C22,6.47 17.5,2 12,2Z" /></svg><span class="title">'+title+'</span></div>'

        $('#billing_phone_field').find('.woocommerce-input-wrapper').append(toolTip) 

    })(jQuery)

</script>
<?php
    }
});
```

the default SVG title will show on hover, you can remove that if you want and use the span `.title` instead

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I prefer to avoid using javascript. Thank you

Comment: Even so, your code only shows the icon, it does not execute the Tooltip

Comment: @gemita, woocommerce wont properly function without javascript, theres no point avoiding it when jQuery itself is embedded in wordpress core. anyway, you can see I commented the hover event CSS  for showing the span `.title` in favor for SVG `title` showing on hover